# How to encode a python list

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I'm having a hard time trying to encode a python list, I already did it with a text file in order to count specific words inside it, using re module.

This is the code:

```
# encoding text file
with codecs.open('projectsinline.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Using re module to extract specific words
        unicode_pattern = re.compile(r'\b\w{4,20}\b', re.UNICODE)
        result = unicode_pattern.findall(line)
    word_counts = Counter(result) # It creates a dictionary key and wordCount
    Allwords = []
    for clave in word_counts:
        if word_counts[clave] >= 10: # We look for the most repeated words
            word = clave
            Allwords.append(word)
    print Allwords
```

Part of the output looks like this:

```
[...u'recursos', u'Partidos', u'Constituci\xf3n', u'veh\xedculos', u'investigaci\xf3n', u'Pol\xedticos']
```

If I `print` variable `word` the output looks as it should be. However, when I use `append`, all the words breaks again, as the example before.

I use this example:

```
[x.encode("utf-8") for x in Allwords]
```

The output looks exactly the same as before.

I also use this example:

```
Allwords.append(str(word.encode("utf-8")))
```

The output change, but the words don't look as they should be:

```
[...'recursos', 'Partidos', 'Constituci\xc3\xb3n', 'veh\xc3\xadculos', 'investigaci\xc3\xb3n', 'Pol\xc3\xadticos']
```

Some of the answers have given this example:

```
print('[' + ', '.join(Allwords) + ']')
```

The output looks like this:

```
[...recursos, Partidos, ConstituciÃ³n, vehÃ­culos, investigaciÃ³n, PolÃ­ticos]
```

To be honest I do not want to print the list, just encode it, so that all items (words) are recognized.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
[...'recursos', 'Partidos', 'Constitución', 'vehículos', 'investigación', 'Políticos']
```

Any suggestions to solve the problem are appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: The words don't break; they are just being shown in the raw format.  `list` uses `__repr__()` to get the string values of its elements.

Comment: is there a solution to show the words with accents inside the list?

Comment: Sort of.  You could do `print("[" + ", ".join(Allwords) + "]")`

Comment: It changes the output, but I got this: `[...recursos, Partidos, ConstituciÃ³n, vehÃ­culos, investigaciÃ³n, PolÃ­ticos]`

Comment: Well, sorry; I don't know how to help you.  Why do you want to print it as a list?

Comment: Don't problem. Thanks! I want to print it as a list because is easier to compare with other text file which contains a bunch of strings. I already obtained what I want, but It doesn't recognize the words with accents. To be honest, I don't want to print the list, just to encode the list in order to use it to compare each item from it with the strings.

Answer (score 0):

you might what to try

print('[' + ', '.join(Allwords) + ']')

Comment: Thanks, @cxad. Using that example I got `[...recursos, Partidos, ConstituciÃ³n, vehÃ­culos, investigaciÃ³n, PolÃ­ticos]` In the other hand, I do not want to print the listm just encode it, so that all items are recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Your Unicode string list is correct. When you print lists the items in the list display as their `repr()` function. When you print the items themselves, the items display as their `str()` function.  It is only a display option, similar to printing integers as decimal or hexadecimal.

So print the individual words if you want to see them correctly, but for comparisons the content is correct.

It's worth noting that Python 3 changes the behavior of `repr()` and now will display non-ASCII characters without escape codes if the terminal supports them directly and the `ascii()` function reproduces the Python 2 `repr()` behavior.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkTolonen! Sometimes is hard to explain what is the main problem. I'm learning, so it is difficult to figure out all the concepts. The problem with my code appears when I want to compare each item from one list with the items from another. So, if I compare the item `social` everything goes ok, but when I compare `ConstituciÃ³n`, the code doesn't recognize the item, so it skips that item.

Comment: The problem was in the text file. I changed the format from UTF-8 to ANSI. Now not only displays the items ok, but it recognizes every item.